# How to record all outputs of Linux terminal to a file

Tags: linux, terminal, spool

For SQL Editors there is a spool command to record all outputs and activities. I would want the same functionality for linux terminal. All the command inputs and outputs typed on the terminal should be recorded into a file, while the output provided should also be available on the stdout of the console that I am using.

Answer (score 4):

This is a job for `script` (comes with `bsdutils`).

You can start a `script` enabled terminal session by:

```
script /path/to/out_file
```

If you do not provide any filename to save the terminal contents, all outputs will be saved in a `typescript` file in the directory from where `script` is invoked.

Also check `man script`.

Comment: note that `script` capture **all** the characters generated, including Ctrl chars like line ending `Ctrl-J` (maybe as `^J`). If you need to show this to non-techies, allow extra time to clean up the `out_file` ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and simplest way of **only** recording output of a command in Linux terminal is to use the redirection operators i.e '>'

Lets say we want to record `ls -alt` commands output in a file. so the command would be :

```
ls -alt > output.txt
```

this will create a file output.txt and write the output to it, if file already exists then it will overwrite that file, (existing information wil be gone)

In case you want to append the output to an existing file the use '>>' instead :

```
ls -alt >> output.txt
```

This will create or append to a file in case it is already there.

To record output as well as print it on `stdout` the command should be

```
ls -alt | tee output.txt
```

This rdirects your output to file as well as `stdout`

If you want botn `stdout` and `stderr` then you have redirect and combine them using the `2>&1` command, which will look like :

```
ls -alt 2>&1 | tee output.txt
```

Here `2` is the file descriptor for `stderr` and `1` is `stdout` (`stdin` fd is 0), so we are redirecting and combining `stderr` with `stdout` because only `stdout` can be piped.

More information can be found in [here](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/using-bash-to-output-to-screen-and-file-at-the-same-time/)